# IE 10 print appears to be scaled down

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-10

I have web application performing report printing.
my code look like this & it works properly.

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Header part
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="reportView">
                    <div class="head centerPosition noPrint">
                        Report header
                    </div>
                    <div class="content" style="margin: 0px;">
                        <div id="report" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                            report content
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="foot noPrint">
                        Report footer
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>    
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
<style media="print">
    body
    {
        background-color:#FFFFFF; 
        margin: 0px;  /* this affects the margin on the content before sending to printer */
        width: 100%;
    }


    #site_header, #site_footer, .noPrint
    {
        visibility: hidden;
        display: none;
        height: 0px !important;
        overflow: hidden !important;
    }


    #report .content
    {
        width: 100%; margin: 0px; float: none;
        background: transparent;
    }

    #report {
        background-color: white;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

After I print any report, the report is scale down on paper.
If anyone have an idea how to fix this please help me. I have try to search on google but none of the suggestion are work.

Thanks in Advance...
[image: Ptinted report look like this]

Comment: obligatory question: did you unzoom accidentally?

Comment: do you have a live page to test?

Comment: this project is live, sorry but not for public

Answer (score 0):

My guess (because I can't test right now) is that you also need to declare `width:100%` on each of the containers above `#report .content` (from the HTML you've provided, it looks like `#reportView` and the `table` and `td` that contains it all, but there may be more).  Otherwise it will collapse to it's content width, which is the default behavior of a table cell.